# Parsing linearized pdf xref table

Tags: parsing, pdf

I have pdf having start as:

```
%PDF-1.7
%‚„œ”

69 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 3937432/O 71/E 2811072/N 9/T 3935937/H [ 996 498]>>
endobj

xref
69 35
0000000016 00000 n

0000001494 00000 n

0000001593 00000 n

0000002065 00000 n
```

........................

and at the end I have:

```
0003929147 00000 n

0003929283 00000 n

0003929352 00000 n

0003929458 00000 n

0003935743 00000 n

trailer
<</Size 69/ID[<00E23EA222C14F40B1305A98D798C27F><F53AB532FC064AB39459DBD6BAF21DD6>]>>
startxref
11
```

Now if I tried to fetch startxref at 11 then I get to „œ” string...which seems wrong, how do I go to actual xrefstart ("xref"),
Can Any body help?

Comment: Also please let me know the incremental update approach for linearized pdf

Comment: Are you sure the startxref is not 116 or something like that?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. It looks prematurely cut- off at the end.

Comment: yes It seems it has missing end string 0 %%EOF , as i modified the same file with adobe ...adobe rewrite the whole file instead of incremental update (as it is corrupted), when I append 0 %%EOF to end making it perfect, adobe too followed incremental update while modifying.  so pdf seems to be incomplete or corrupted . well Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

Your `xref` table byte offset is wrong. It is not 11.

```
startxref
11
```

If you fixed this, you can access the `xref` reading properly